API authentication and authorization with auto login via embedded script
Overview
I am developing an api (a web service, REST API)
and my web service is hosted on, say web-apis.com

Assuming I have clients/customers with respective websites

customer-1 (website-1.com),
customer-2 (website-2.com),
customer-3 (website-3.com)
and so on....

I want that my registered clients/customers should only be able to call/consume the apis on web-apis.com

Also, I want that my client websites website-1.com, website-2.com etc. login (in the backend) into my service web-apis.com as soon as any web page is visited by the site visitor. I do not want any login form for the site visitors (of my client's websites website-1.com, website-2.com), since my service is enabling some functionality on their website and not intended directly for the site visitors.

How do I achieve this?
To sumup..

only my registered clients should be able to fetch apis on my portal.
the client's website sholud automatically login and authenticate as soon as any page is visited on their website. I would like to give some script to my client which could be embeded and globally accessible in their respective domain.

So how to achieve this? Is this possible. Which library is the best to achieve this?
